# foundation datepicker datesdisabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I am trying to disable holidays in my calendar but can't seem to pass the right format to the `datesdisabled` option.

I have

```
$('#booking').fdatepicker({
    var now = new Date();
    $('#booking').fdatepicker({
        format: 'dd MM yyyy',
        startDate: now,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 4, 5],
        datesDisabled:['2018-02-13']
    });
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way, as it doesn't support the way you are using it. Also, it doesn't support time, just date.

```
$(function(){
    $('#dpt').fdatepicker({
        initialDate: new Date(),
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
        disableDblClickSelection: true,
        language: 'es',
        pickTime: true,
        datesDisabled:['2018-01-15']
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dferenc for the suggestion. The datepicker is working will in production except for not being able to disable certain dates (i.e. public holidays)

Unfortunately the format you have suggested for disabling dates is not working either.

FYI - you will notice I am not using time for this datepicker.

`jquery-1.11.0.min.js`
`jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js`
`foundation-datepicker v1.5.0`

Comment: @BryanHickey the author of the answer is actually tiranox85, I just formatted it a bit.

Comment: @BryanHickey, perhaps the date format you are using is a bit different from the example, this is the way i've been using it, i just send an array of dates and voila. Just check that all the dates are in the same format, i bet you that's the problem.